# Dynamically assign name values to all children?

Tags: jquery, html, loops, dynamic

I am cloning field sets and need to increment the name values by 1 each time.

Here is jquery:

```
i = 2;
$("#AddOne").click(function () {
    if (i < 11) {
        var itemNum = "<div class='iSep'>Item "+ i +"</div>";
        $("#cloneSet").clone().prepend(itemNum).appendTo("#cloneRet");
        i++;
    }
});
```

Here is the relevant HTML:

```
<div id="cloneSet">
<label for="ModelNumber1">Model Number:</label>
<input type="text" name="ModelNumber1" class="required"><br />
<label for="SerialNumber1">Serial Number:</label>
<input type="text" name="SerialNumber1" class="required"><br />
<label for="ConditionofUnit1">Condition of Unit:</label>
<select name="ConditionofUnit1" class="required">
<option value="">Choose an option</option> 
<option value="Open: Defective">Open: Defective</option>
<option value="Open: Non-defective">Open: Non-defective</option>
<option value="Factory Sealed">Factory Sealed</option>
</select><br />
</div>

<div id="cloneRet"></div>
```

So on all the form elements including the labels, i want to increment 1 to i for all of the for and name values.. can anyone help please?

Comment: use a class as semantically id can be applied to one element only

Comment: thanks, changed to use class

Answer (score 0):

Updating all for and name attributes as you go along

Honestly dont know why you want to do this, and i would advise using classes

However, that was not your question.

```
i = 2;
$("#AddOne").click(function () {
    if (i < 11) {
        var itemNum = "<div class='iSep'>Item "+ i +"</div>";
        $("#cloneSet:first").clone().prepend(itemNum).appendTo("#cloneRet")
        .children().each(function(){
             $(this).attr('name',$(this).attr('name').replace(i,i+1))
             $(this).attr('for',$(this).attr('for').replace(i,i+1))
        });
        i++;
    }
});
```

Comment: It's for a very temporary solution where i need to email a form with ASP. I don't know anything about ASP so I had to hard-code 10 of each of the fields to send off in email lol. Hence why i need to increment each name field because thats what it uses to get the values... yeah

Comment: Hey i'm inspecting elements with firebug and i don't see the values changing using this code

Comment: Yeah this isn't working. I changed it to use classes with this and when i add my extra fields i doesn't auto-increment anymore, it stays at 2